# Why does R raster::writeRaster() generate a pic which can't be shown in Win10?

Tags: r, tiff, envi

I read my hyperspectral (.raw) file and combine three bands to "gai_out_r" Then I output as following:

```
writeRaster(gai_out_r,filepath,format="GTiff")
```

finally I got gai_out_r.tif

But, why Win10 can't display this small tif as the pic that I output the same way from envi--save image as--tif

Two tiffs are displayed by Win10 as following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Default windows image viewing applications doesn't support Hyperspectral Images-since you are just reading and combining 3 bands from your .raw file, the resulting image will be a hyperspectral image.You need to have separate dedicated softwares to view hypercubes or can view it using spectral-python also.

In sPy, using [envi.save_image](http://www.spectralpython.net/class_func_ref.html#envi-save-image) , will save it as a ENVI type file only. To save it as an rgb image file(readable in windows OS) we need to use other methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot !
But how dose it mean: "three bands in an image it will come under a Hyperspectral image"?
In my opion, .jpg or .tif is also a three-band image in this case?
Or is there any other knowledge about image format I should learn...
Looking forward to your reply ^_^

Comment: What I meant was using `envi.save_image` will save it as a hypercube with the band number you specify. We can save it as a normal colour image with 3 bands for (R,G,B) using differnt commands like `save_rgb`. I'm not that familiar with R, but this is with respect to sPy.

Comment: I got that. I am sure it will work. However, I still want to know what's the difference between just stacking rgb bands together and `save_rgb`. It may concerns the data format stored by computer?
I will try to use sPy to find out that. Thanks again!

Comment: I kind of edited my answer to answer what I could ,to your query.

Comment: The ```R``` function ```raster::writeRaster()``` is perfectly capable of writing a *.tif* file Windows understands. You don't have to save it as *.png* or use other programs. You just need to pass the correct options to ```writeRaster()``` (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Cause of the issue:**

I had a similar issue and recognised that the exported *.tif* files had a different bit depth than *.tif* images I could open. The images could not be displayed using common applications, although they were not broken and I could open them in R or QGIS. Hence, the values were coded in a way Windows would not expect.

When you type `?writeRaster()` you will find that there are various options when it comes to saving a *.tif* (or other format) using the `raster::writeRaster()` function. Click on the links therein to get to the `dataType {raster}` help site and you'll find there are various integer types to choose from.

**Solution (write a Windows-readable GeoTIFF):**

I set the following options to make the resulting *.tif* file readable (note the `datatype` option):

```
writeRaster(raster, filename = "/path/to/your/output.tif",
            format = "GTiff", datatype = "INT1U")
```

**Note:**
I realised your post is from 2 and a half years ago... Anyways, may this answer help others who encounter this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `writeRaster` to write to a GTiff (GeoTiff) format file. To write to a standard tif file you can use the `tiff` method. With `writeRaster` you could also write to a PNG instead

```
writeRaster(gai_out_r, "gai.png")
```